# django Display Uploaded photo in template

Tags: django, django-templates

in my UserProfile app i'm trying to add a photo Upload ,in the admin panel i can see the photo link  when i upload it from user profile and it work fine but i can't display it in my template

urls.oy

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user')    
        photo = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)

        def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
            user = kwargs["instance"]
            if kwargs["created"]:
                user_profile = UserProfile(user=user)
                user_profile.save()
        post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

in my template i tried all this combinations but none works

```
<div>  <img  src="{{user.user.photo}}" alt="image example"/>
            <img  src="{{user.photo.url}}" alt="image example"/>
            <img  src="{{user.image.url}}" alt="image example"/>
            <img  src="{{instance.photo.url}}" alt="image example"/>
            <img  src="{{instance.image.url}}" alt="image example"/>
            <img  src="{{UserProfile.photo.url}}" alt="image example"/>
            <img  src="{{UserProfile.image.url}}" alt="image example"/>



    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, since I have `related_name='user'`, I needed to the photo path.url mean

```
{{user.user.photo.url}}
```

but if i didn't have related_name='user' the path would be

```
{{user.UserProfile.photo.url}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your file is uploaded?

Please check the [File upload documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/) of django to make sure that you handle the uploaded files.

If everything is right you must see some files uploaded to MEDIA_URL folder that you specified in settings.

Comment: yes i checked from admin panel the image displays well in this link  http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/1_zmH5bU4.png PS: the original photo name is 1.png and '_zmH5bU4' is randomly generated if i upload another photo with the same name to the directory